# How do I search in multiple 7-Zip archives?

Tags: search, 7-zip

7z command line has a very fast search feature allowing to find files contained in a compressed folder. This is the syntax:

```
7z l mycompressedfile.7z fileiwant.txt -r
```

It works also on multiple compressed files contained in a folder:

```
7z l *.7z fileiwant.txt -r
```

My question is how can apply this feature to all the files contained in a folder or disk, recursing all the subfolders?
for example, I want to search "fileiwant.txt" in all the zip files contained in any folder on disk D:

```
7z l [unknown option] d:\*.7z fileiwant.txt -r
```

I couldn't find any option to do that, beside scripting in PowerShell, but it's complicated, I'd like a single line, easy to remember.

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

The windows command Forfiles can let you run a command over files in a directory and its subdirectories.

The syntax for your needs is the following :

```
forfiles /s /M *.7z /c "cmd /c 7z l @file fileiwant.txt -r"
```

Forfiles iterate over all .7z files (`/M *.7z`) in the current directory and its subdirectories (`/s`). It apply your 7z command for each files (`/c "cmd /c 7z l @file fileiwant.txt -r"`)

Source : https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Similar but more succinct than the PS I found as I stated in my Q, i.e.
foreach ($myzip in cmd /C where /R d:\ *.7z) { 
  7z l $myzip fileiwant.txt -r 
} 
However I was looking for a 7z option doing all of it without other commands, bc that gives also a general report of all the inspected archives which is lost when you process one by one. I found the option, see the answer to my original Q. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found the option in 7z, thanks to the author of 7-zip

here is the syntax:

```
7z l -an -air!d:\*.zip fileiwant.txt -r
```

it is fast and produces a single global report of all inspected archives